# getDerivedStateFromProps and multiple checking props

Tags: reactjs

When we have a react component and it takes many props, do I really need to check all of them step by step?

Is there any simpler way to check all of the props? I know that maybe by id, would be the easiest, am I right?

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, state) {
    if (nextProps.currentUserProfile !== state.currentUserProfile) {
      return {
        name: nextProps.currentUserProfile.name,
        lastName: nextProps.currentUserProfile.lastName,
        street: nextProps.currentUserProfile.street,
        city: nextProps.currentUserProfile.city,
        phoneNo: nextProps.currentUserProfile.phoneNo,
        postalCode: nextProps.currentUserProfile.postalCode,
        flatNo: nextProps.currentUserProfile.flatNo,
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The above code is an example, when we have many fields to check, and if we do not have an id, we need to check every prop with every field in state. Am I right?

Regards

Comment: what is the check you are trying to perform? (e.g. check for value, check if not empty, etc...)

Comment: @JamalAbo let's say it's only data to fill up the form, but could be editing existing object (that's why this lifecycle method) or creating the new one, that's why the state is initialized with empty values.